# Android - wait for animation to finish before continuing?

Tags: android, animation, wait

I've spend quite a while trying to find out how to wait for an animation to finish before continuing the code.
So far I've tried while(animation.hasEnded() == False), using Thread.sleep, using a timer but can't seem to get anything to work.

Something that cropped up quite a few times was to add an Animation Listener to the animation, which I've tried but not sure how to progress this further.

I create the animation, start the animation and then have a line of code after, which I only want to be executed after the animation has finished:

```
    Animation moveDown = allAnimStuff(duration); //creates animation 

    image.startAnimation(moveDown); // Start the animation
    displayScore(score); // wait for animation to finish before executing this line
```

and here is the allAnimStuff(duration) method used to create the animation:

```
private Animation allAnimStuff(final long duration) {

        Animation moveDown = new TranslateAnimation(image.getX(), image.getX(), (-image.getHeight()), pxHeight - image.getHeight() / 2); //creates animation
        moveDown.setDuration(duration);
        moveDown.setFillAfter(false);

        moveDown.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                 //some code to make it wait here? 
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                image.setY((pxHeight / 2 - image.getHeight()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });


        return moveDown;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write following line in onAnimationEnd method

```
 displayScore(score);
```

for example

```
private Animation allAnimStuff(final long duration) {

        Animation moveDown = new TranslateAnimation(image.getX(), image.getX(), (-image.getHeight()), pxHeight - image.getHeight() / 2); //creates animation
        moveDown.setDuration(duration);
        moveDown.setFillAfter(false);

        moveDown.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                 //some code to make it wait here? 
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                image.setY((pxHeight / 2 - image.getHeight()));
             displayScore(score);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });


        return moveDown;
    }
```

Comment: If your problem is resolved then please accept the answer.

Comment: That works for now but if I then want more lines of code to run after the animation has finished do I have to basically have my whole code in the onAnimationEnd method?

Comment: I found a way around my issue in the comment, thanks a lot for the simple solution!